# Software running faster when using symbolic link to a network location

Tags: windows, networking, symlink, mapped-drive

while testing our software for performance issues (we had a huge difference when the software was on a network drive), we found something really weird.

Just to have some context, our software is a C++ program which use Adobe library to rip pdf pages. We already know who is the faulty one (it's the Cooltype dll from Adobe), but we are more wondering how is it possible to have such differences.

So, basically we launched our software tests from different hardware locations. Each time we go to the location through windows explorer and run it from there.

- If the software is on the **local drive** (*D:\TestLocal\*), it takes **19 seconds**.
- If the software is on a network location and we access it using **UNC path** (*\\Fileserver_A\Development\TestNetwork\*), it takes **2 minutes 44 seconds**. Up to now, it's ok (even if there is a huge gap in time).
- If I map a network drive (*J:\*) to the network location *\\Fileserver_A\\Development\*, and use the **mapped network drive**(*J:\TestNetwork\*) to access my folder through windows explorer, it only takes **1 minute 43 seconds**.
- If I create a **symbolic link** on *D:\* to the network drive (*mklink /D D:\TestLink\ \\Fileserver_A\Development\TestNetwork\*) and access the software location through *D:\TestLink\*, it takes **29 seconds**

I don't know at all what this dll do since it's a 3rd party dll, I only know that it loads a lot of small files (180) which are at the same location than the executable. That will explain the huge difference between local/network.

But that doesn't explain why accessing the exact same location through mapped drive give a little boost in speed (2'44" down to 1'43") and accessing it using a symbolic link made on a local drive gives even more increase in speed (2'44" down to 29"). Each time, it is the exact same software on the exact same network location which is launched.

Of course, we did the same tests on other computers in the company. Depending on the network connection the figures change (with a better network connection : 1'03" with UNC, 45" with mapped drive, 28" with symlink), but each time we have better results with symbolic link.

If anybody has the slightest idea on what can cause such differences, I'm all ears.

**Edit** : Using Process Monitor, I can see a difference in execution. When trying to load one of the small files, it does something on the root of the drive. 
With symbolic link on D:, it's only done one time before each file:

```
CreateFile  D:\ SUCCESS Desired Access: Synchronize, Disposition: Open, Options: Directory, Synchronous IO Non-Alert, Attributes: n/a, ShareMode: None, AllocationSize: n/a, OpenResult: Opened
QueryNameInformationFile    D:\ SUCCESS Name: \
QueryAttributeInformationVolume D:\ SUCCESS FileSystemAttributes: Case Preserved, Case Sensitive, Unicode, ACLs, Compression, Named Streams, EFS, Object IDs, Reparse Points, Sparse Files, Quotas, Transactions, 0x3c00000, MaximumComponentNameLength: 255, FileSystemName: NTFS
CloseFile   D:\ SUCCESS
```

But when it's a network drive, it repeats it 35 times before each file!!!

```
CreateFile  \\Fileserver_A\Development\ IS DIRECTORY    Desired Access: Read Attributes, Synchronize, Disposition: Open, Options: Synchronous IO Non-Alert, Non-Directory File, Attributes: n/a, ShareMode: Read, Write, AllocationSize: n/a
CreateFile  \\Fileserver_A\Development\ SUCCESS Desired Access: Read Attributes, Synchronize, Disposition: Open, Options: Synchronous IO Non-Alert, Open Reparse Point, Attributes: N, ShareMode: Read, Write, AllocationSize: n/a, OpenResult: Opened
FileSystemControl   \\Fileserver_A\Development\ NOT REPARSE POINT   Control: FSCTL_GET_REPARSE_POINT
CloseFile   \\Fileserver_A\Development\ SUCCESS 
CreateFile  \\Fileserver_A\Development\ SUCCESS Desired Access: Read Attributes, Synchronize, Disposition: Open, Options: Synchronous IO Non-Alert, Attributes: n/a, ShareMode: Read, Write, AllocationSize: n/a, OpenResult: Opened
QueryDeviceInformationVolume    \\Fileserver_A\Development\ SUCCESS DeviceType: Disk, Characteristics: Remote
CloseFile   \\Fileserver_A\Development\ SUCCESS
```

Comment: Try using Process Monitor to see if the DLL is doing something odd on the filesystem.  It might, for example, be using the root of the path for something - D:\, J:\, or \\FileServer_A.

Comment: @HarryJohnston No, nothing suspicious. I also tried to map directly \\Fileserver_A\Development\TestNetwork\ as a network drive and the time is the same than when mapping \\Fileserver_A\Development\ (which has a lot of folders/files)

Comment: If nothing else, Process Monitor should show you when the delay is occurring; is it a single operation that's taking forever, or tens of thousands of separate operations taking a few milliseconds each?

Comment: @HarryJohnston I edited my initial post. It seems your first idea was maybe a good one (sorry I didn't notice it before). It's trying to do something with the root of my folder before each file it needs to load. When it's a local drive it works on the first attempt, but on a network drive it repeats the same operation 35 times before loading the file... Don't know why.

Comment: Sounds like the DLL just doesn't handle network roots well. I can tell you a few ways to accomplish that "feature", but that's not really going to help you - you already know your answer, use a symlink (assuming the DLL does actually work *correctly* using a symplink). There's any number of ways the DLL might be handling the paths (or handles) incorrectly.

Comment: @Luaan Yes, using a symlink works well. The only drawback is I have to create this symlink on every client machine.
What do you mean by "I can tell you a few ways to accomplish that feature" ?

Comment: Just how to make an application that breaks horribly when used with UNC paths :) Anyway, you could automate creating the symlinks - since it's your application, just use the relevant APIs to setup the symlink while you need it (with a fallback to the UNC path if that's not possible, for example on FAT32), and tear it down when you exit.